# How do i get the distancies between frames in openni_tracker?

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!
I'm running ROS hydro with ubuntu 12.04 (I'm new for both of them).
I'm using kinect for skeletal tracking, but I don't know how to get the length of the limbs during a movement.
Can someone help me?
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203270/how-do-i-get-the-distancies-between-frames-in-openni_tracker?/) by [chiaraDark](https://answers.ros.org/users/21660/chiaradark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using `openni_tracker`, the general way to do this would be to create a [tf listener](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29), and in some sort of loop use the listener to lookup the transform between the joints that you're interested in. This method will return a vector and a quaternion representing the transform between the two frames. If all you're interested in is distance, then you can simply calculate that using the transformation vector. Here's a simple example adapted from the previously-linked tf listener tutorial:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
import rospy
import tf
import geometry_msgs.msg
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('tf_lookup_example')

    listener = tf.TransformListener()

    rate = rospy.Rate(10.0)
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            (trans,rot) = listener.lookupTransform('/right_hand_1', '/left_hand_1', rospy.Time(0))
            rospy.loginfo("Distance between the hands is = {0:f}".format(np.linalg.norm(trans)))
        except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException):
            continue

        rate.sleep()
```

The only key to making this example work is ensuring that your tf tree is fully connected. My version of `openni_tracker` uses, by default, `openni_depth_frame` as the frame it produces transforms in, but the `openni.launch` file uses `camera` as its default name to define all frames and topics. This inconsistency can be fixed, for example, by running `openni.launch` in the following way:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch camera:=openni
```

Then `openni_tracker` could be started with just `rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker`

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chiaraDark](https://answers.ros.org/users/21660/chiaradark/) on 2015-02-17**:
Is the same if i run this command in the terminal?
rosrun tf tf_echo right_shoulder_1 right_hand_1
With this i get a vector for translation and one for rotation, but what i need is the effective registered length of the limb (i have to see if my track is affected by noise and i have to measure it)

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-02-17**:
The "trans" part in my code is exactly the vector for translation. If you want, for example, the length of the right forearm simply lookup the transform from "/right_hand_1" to "/right_elbow_1". That will give you a translation between those frames. Then the Euclidean norm will give the distance.

**Comment by [chiaraDark](https://answers.ros.org/users/21660/chiaradark/) on 2015-02-17**:
Thanks a lot!